# Can't get the last name to display properly in Oracle Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, logic, plsqldeveloper

So, I have an issue. This compiles, but if the person has a middle initial with a "." the middle initial will be included in the last_nm column.  For instance Julie L. Roberts last_nm is displayed as "L. Roberts" instead of roberts. The starred part of the code is where the problem lies. If I change the instr statement to search for a "." + 1 then I fix it, but if the person does not have a "." there full name is displayed in the last_nm column.

```
   NVL (
      LTRIM (
         RTRIM (
            REPLACE (
                  RTRIM (vw_party_person.first_nm)
               || ' '
               || LTRIM (RTRIM (vw_party_person.mid_nm))
               || ' '
               || LTRIM (vw_party_person.last_nm),
               '  ',
               ' '))),
      full_nm)
      full_nm,
   former_nm,
   party_hist_eff_dt,
   party_hist_exp_dt,
   **NVL (vw_party_person.first_nm,
        SUBSTR (DECODE (full_nm, 'null full name', NULL, full_nm),
                1,
                instrc (full_nm,
                        ' ',
                        1,
                        1)))
      first_nm,
   NVL (vw_party_person.last_nm,
        SUBSTR (DECODE (full_nm, 'null full name', NULL, full_nm),
                instrc (full_nm,
                        ' ',
                        1,
                        1)
                + 1))
      last_nm**
  FROM adw.pol_term_party_snapshot,
   vw_party_person,
   vw_party,
   vw_party_hist
```

Answer (score 0):

Why go about parsing the last name back out from the full name when it appears the last name is available as vw_party_person.last_nm?

Anyway. To fix what you have listed in your question...

```
**NVL (vw_party_person.first_nm,
    SUBSTR (DECODE (full_nm, 'null full name', NULL, full_nm),
            1,
            instrc (full_nm,
                    ' ',
                    1,
                    1)))
  first_nm,
NVL (vw_party_person.last_nm,
    SUBSTR (DECODE (full_nm, 'null full name', NULL, full_nm),
            DECODE (instrc (full_nm, ' ', 1,2),
                    0, instrc (full_nm, ' ', 1,1),
                    instrc (full_nm, ' ', 1,2))
            + 1))
  last_nm**
```

INSTRC returns 0 if a string is not found. So the decode uses INSTRC to look for the 2nd appearance of ' ' and if it is not found (0) then return the position of the first occurrence of the ' '. Other wise return the position of the 2nd  occurrence of ' '.

This is still not a good way to parse names as you depending on nationality and formatting you can have more than 2 spaces in a name. But with the information you provided in the question this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: I actually just figured out the problem.  Instead of instrc (full_nm,1,1)+1)) for the last name, I did instrc(full_nm,-1,1))) so it would start from the end of the name and work back to determine the second position. Thanks for the help

Comment: I was going to suggest that having done a good bit of address parsing in the past, it's almost always better to start at the end.  But you are depending on names fitting a specific format.  What about hyphenated last names.  Parsing is very difficult when you take into account all the variations of how people put in their names.  What if someone put's in Jr., Sr., or III at the end of their last name.